# Concatenate two or more songs

Tags: linux, concatenation

I tried three different methods in order to concatenate songs

- Audacity: Works, but it adds a "click" sound between the first and second song
- cat command: I tried `cat *.wma > result.wma` and `cat second.wma >> first.wma`. Both have the same problem, the resulting file is just the first one.
- ffmpeg:  `ffmpeg -i "concat:uno.wma|dos.wma" -acodec copy result.wma`, same problem as cat command, the file result.wma is a copy of uno.wma

Any help?

Comment: You're unlikely to ever get rid of the click by hard cutting two tracks together. You'll need a *very* short mix to make it sound right, i.e make it sound like a hard cut without a click. You also can't just "concatenate" two files together, they're not raw audio, but a real file format.

Comment: http://superuser.com better suits your question

Comment: @Joe What tool do you recommend me?

Comment: @user3159253 I will try there

Answer (score 1):

You should use ">>" operator instead of ">", because ">" overrides the result of first operation. But, I'm not sure about the correctness of this operation on audio files.

Example:

```
$ echo "1" > output
$ echo "2" > output
$ cat output 
2
$ echo "1" >> output2
$ echo "2" >> output2
$ cat output2
1
2
```

If you write: `cat *.wma > result.wma`, actually you do:

```
cat 1.wma > result.wma
cat 2.wma > result.wma
```

So, you'll get 2.wma in result.wma, without 1.wma in it.

Comment: I am not sure if you understood what I am doing

Comment: But I do :-) I've updated the answer. Check out the example.

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg concat protocol you're using (the "concat:" pattern) does not work for concatenating some media files like WMA and WAV.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Likely because they have some headers at the beginning of their files. At least, WAV files have a 46 byte file header if made with ffmpeg. These headers are likely also tripping up the playback of files concatenated with the `cat` command.

So try this for generic concatenation instead:

```
ffmpeg -i "first.wma" -i "second.wma" -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out]' -map '[out]' result.wma
```

See related question and answer (for WAV files):

https://superuser.com/q/587511/192525

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
cat song1.wma song2.wma > bothsongs.wma
```

Comment: Still not working, the result now its a copy of the second song